# Proving that an iteration of integrals converges

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

First off, this is homework, so please give hints/suggestions rather than full solutions. 
Secondly, I wish to show that the iteration

$u^{(n+1)}(\textbf{x})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\exp^{-|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}|}}{4\pi|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}|}\alpha f(\textbf{y})g(u^{(n)}(\textbf{y}))d\textbf{y}$

converges to the solution

$u(\textbf{x})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\exp^{-|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}|}}{4\pi|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}|}\alpha f(\textbf{y})g(u(\textbf{y}))d\textbf{y}$

for "sufficiently small $\alpha$" given that $f(\textbf{x})\to0$ faster than any polynomial in $|\textbf{x}|$ and where $g$ is a bounded Lipschitz function (with Lipschitz constant $L_g$). (And $|\textbf{z}|$ denotes the standard norm on vectors.)

Now, what I've done is let $\epsilon_n = \|u^{(n)}-u\|$ and use properties of integrals and the Lipschitz property of $g$ to get

$\epsilon_{n+1}=\|u^{n+1}-u\|\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\|\frac{\exp^{-|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}|}}{4\pi|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}|}\|\cdot\alpha \cdot \|f(\textbf{y})\|\cdot L_g\cdot \epsilon_n d\textbf{y}$

which I can rearrange to show

$\frac{\epsilon_{n+1}}{\epsilon_n}\leq \frac{1}{4\pi}\alpha\|f\|L_g\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\|\frac{\exp^{-|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}|}}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}|}\|d\textbf{y}$

The problem here is that the integral does not converge, but I wish to show that the right-hand side of this inequality is really less than 1 because that would prove that the iteration converges. Are there any hints/suggestions about what I should be looking at and/or where my logic is invalid? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check again the condition on $f$, it does not make much sense in the present form.

Use a reparametrisation of the integral in terms of spherical coordinates,
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty\int_{S^n}f(r·s)\,r\,ds\,dr
$$
which should help to cancel the denominator.

Comment: The condition on $f$ is  exactly what I've been given. I believe we are to assume that it is also continuous (since we have been talking about test functions), so $f$ would then be bounded.

Comment: It's just that convergence to zero and polynomial makes a strange combination. Probably the intention is to say that $f(x)·p(x)$ stays bounded for any polynomial $p$? But that is certainly overkill for this problem.